# Error getting an output from a users selection bash shell in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, unix, io

He friends. I am creating a script file to be able to read users input and display an output based on the question i am asking. When i run the choices separately they work fine but cant figure out why they will not display when i put pieces together.

```
#!/bin/bash
while test $loop = "y"
do
echo "$CLEAR"
clear
tput cup 5 12 ; echo "L- List all wines by name in alphabetical order."
tput cup 6 12 ; echo "C- Count all wines in each type and list all 5 types with their count."
tput cup 10 12; echo "E- Exit the program."
read choice || continue
case $choice in
[Ll]) file="/home/students/domie/wine.txt"; sort -t ":" -k2 $file;; #no output here
[Cc]) ./count ;;  #look below for count script
[Ee]) clear;  exit ;; #this works when script runs
*) tput cup 14 4; echo "Invalid Code,Press Enter and Try Again"; read choice ;;
esac
done
```

and the count script:

$vi count

```
while IFS=":" read -ra line; do
if (( ${line[2]} == 2 )); then
    IFS=":" && echo "${line[*]}"
    (( count++ ))

fi
done < /home/students/domie/wine.txt
echo "Count = $count"
```

EDITED:
[wine.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgm2e38mn895gbs/wine.txt)

Comment: What do you mean by _putting the pieces together_?

Comment: Post sample data from your `wine.txt` file.

Comment: when i run the main script, and choose option L (List all wines by name in alphabetical order.) the list will not show up. When i run this command separately it will display the list in order, but it wont when i put it in the main script.
file="/home/students/domie/wine.txt"; sort -t ":" -k2 $file

Comment: @JS웃 oh sorry, wine.txt added at the bottom.

Comment: @endri That count script is from my answer to your previous question. How is that being used to count different types of wines? It is only checking the third column and if it is 2 it is printing and counting the times it has printed. Also there is no `$loop` variable set anywhere that you are testing.

Comment: @JS웃 first option (lL) is to simply list, second option (cC) is to do the counting. This is where the while loop is, in the count script.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that the count script is only counting and printing lines where third column is 2. It does not do what you want - `"Count all wines in each type and list all 5 types with their count."`

Comment: @JS웃 yes, i am working now to try to show them all, but my question here is that why wont it run in this script when i choose its particular option?

Comment: Change `while test $loop = "y"` to `while :` and try

Comment: (just figured out how to show all the 5 types of wine and count)
just did what you suggested, it will display it for a split second and not remain on screen

Comment: Remove all `clear` syntax from your code.

Comment: i have tried that before, but this will not clear the screen ever. everything will be on the screen..hmm

Comment: @endri Try the solution I have posted below. You just need to put in your new counting logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin /bash

file="wine.txt"
count() {
    # Replace below with your counting logic .. 
    while IFS=":" read -ra line; do
        if (( ${line[2]} == 2 )); then
        IFS=":" && echo "${line[*]}"
        (( count++ ))
    fi
    done < "$file"
    echo "Count = $count"
}

pause() {
    read -p "$*"
}

while :; do
    clear
    echo "L- List all wines by name in alphabetical order."
    echo "C- Count all wines in each type and list all 5 types with their count."
    echo "E- Exit the program."
    read -p "Enter Choice: " choice || continue
    case $choice in
        [Ll]) sort -t ":" -k2,2 "$file" ; pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue...';;
        [Cc]) count ; pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue...';;  
        [Ee]) exit ;; 
           *) pause "Invalid Code, Press Enter and Try Again" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: @ JS웃
YOU ARE A GENIUS!! :) i would really like to show my appreciation and donate something for your help, please let me know where i can. and thank you again

Comment: Thank you @endri. Your compliment was more than enough! `:)`